# swift 4 Constraint animation does not work correctly

Tags: ios, animation, constraints, swift4

I have custom tapbar, which contains collectionView with 4 items.  i had white view which indicates selected item and change its position (with animation) while tapping another collectionView item. White view positioning with constraints and i change the left anchor constraint to animate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let x = CGFloat(indexPath.item) * frame.width / 4
        self.horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = x
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Animation does not work correctly, at the beginning its jums to position on 1 width (of white view) before the current position and start animation from that position

I find the problem // 
I had another animation of this constraint to response of scrolling the collection view, and here  i had double animation which produce such jumping, i delete the second animation and now everything looks well

Answer (score 1):

You not set any animation conditions, maybe I not understand your question. But you should use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // BEFORE ANIMATION CONTEXT

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

    // ANIMATION TILL END CONTEXT
    self.layoutIfNeeded

    }, completion: {

    // AFTER ANIMATION CONTEXT

    })
}
```

Comment: self.horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint property was set before and in this func i change its value and than ask to redraw the view in animation block

Comment: The value in animation context should be different, in the block should be not same x to animate

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

       let x = CGFloat(indexPath.item) * frame.width / 4
       self.horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = x
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```